# How to perform a different CI/CD pipeline for each directory

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, github-actions

In my project, I have a different directory for each language that the project is coded in (the project has a version in node, python, java, etc.). I want a different CI build to run depending on which directory was changed, so I want to make a different config file for each language and put it in its respective directory, and then only run the specific directory based on what changed. Is it possible to do this on CircleCI, or GitHub Actions?

Comment: What you describe is similar to how monorepos work. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136732/11934042) will help you for GitHub Actions.

Comment: @peterevans thank you! this is exactly what i need